# How do I know if a file has been dumped in badrecordspath ? [ Azure Databricks -Spark]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, corrupt

I want to use `badrecordspath` in Spark in  in Azure Databricks to get a count of corrupt records associated to the job, but there is no simple way to know :

- if a file has been written
- in which partition the file has been written

I thought maybe i could check **if the last partition was created in the last 60** seconds with some code like that :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import datetime

df = spark.read.format('csv').option("badRecordsPath", corrupt_record_path)

partition_dict = {} #here the dictionnary of partition and corresponding timestamp
for i in dbutils.fs.ls(corrupt_record_path):
  partition_dict[i.name[:-1]]=time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(i.name[:-1], "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S").timetuple())


#here i get the timestamp of one minute ago  
submit_timestamp_utc_minus_minute = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo = timezone.utc) - timedelta(seconds=60)
submit_timestamp_utc_minus_minute = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(submit_timestamp_utc_minus_minute.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"), "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S").timetuple())

#Here i compare the latest partition to check if is more recent than 60 seconds ago
if partition_dict[max(partition_dict, key=lambda k: partition_dict[k])]>submit_timestamp_utc_minus_minute :
  corrupt_dataframe = spark.read.format('json').load(corrupt_record_path+partition+'/bad_records')
  corrupt_records_count = corrupt_dataframe.count()
else:
  corrupt_records_count = 0
```

But i see two issues :

- it is a lot of overhead (ok the code could also be better written, but
  still)
- i'm not even sure when does the partition name is defined in    the
  reading job. Is it at the beginning of the job or at the end ? If it is at the beginning, then the 60 seconds are not relevant at all.

As a side note i cannot use PERMISSIVE read with corrupt_records_column, as i don't want to cache the dataframe (you can see my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233611/how-can-i-query-corrupt-records-without-caching-the-data-in-spark) )

Any suggestion or observation would be much appreciated !